# Future super-continent

Tags: climate, plate-tectonics, earth-history

What will the earth look like when the continents recollide? What will the climate be like? Assume global warming has been taken care of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of very cool animations on YouTube of the future supercontinent: Pangea Proxima. One is by [Christopher Scotese](http://www.scotese.com/) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2It3ETk2MGA)) and the other is by Algol ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQywDr-btz4) or also a [longer animation](http://davidson16807.github.io/3billionyears/#) with a longer history). The [PALEOMAP Project](http://www.scotese.com/) page contains a fair amount of information as to how they estimate the evolution. With regard to the future climate, that is a really tough question that I don't feel qualified to answer.

Also, even though it does not include the future supercontinent, I really like the [EarthViewer](http://www.hhmi.org/biointeractive/earthviewer-online-and-downloadable-version) interactive tool. It has lots of information and it is very intuitive to use.

Comment: Before the 'when' there's an 'if'. Plate tectonics is driven by heat from radioactive decay. Sooner or later that energy will decay to the point where plate tectonics slows and finally grinds to a halt. There's no guarantee that the next super-continent will have accreted by then.

Comment: @GordonStanger I don't remember where, but in one of the answers here on SE someone mentioned that the sun will engulf the earth by the time radioactive heat decays.

Comment: Long before the sun engulfs the Earth it will continue to warm until the Earth gets too hot to sustain photosynthesis, which will of course mean .'curtains' for us. But Michael is right. Neither the cessation of plate tectonics, nor the 'heat death' can be timed precisely. Also bear in mind that some radioactive decay will continue long after it is insufficient to drive the tectonic engine. This will likely lead to volcanoes of unusually deep origin.